# Shorter way to parse this byte

Tags: python, parsing, bit-manipulation, byte

Is there a shorter way to this in python?

```
        if byte is 1:
            return 0
        if byte is 2:
            return 1
        if byte is 4:
            return 2
        if byte is 8:
            return 3
        if byte is 64:
            return 4
        if byte is 128:
            return 5
```

Im using python2.7

Creating a dictionary is possible but still quite long, is there a mathematical way?
Thanks.

Comment: How about a dictionary that maps the inputs to the outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Details

If you insist on a non-dictionary solution, you can use logarithms base 2 and some Boolean operations as follows.

First obtain the logarithm base 2 from your input byte `b` (in some languages denoted `lg(b)`, but I do not know Pythonian; and beware of `log`: in most languages this denotes the logarithm base 10).

If there is no such function in your language, use the natural logarithm for conversion as follows: `n=ln(b)/ln(2)`. For `b` you obtain the following `n`:

```
b   n

1   0
2   1
4   2
8   3
64  6
128 7
```

On this intermediate result `n`, apply some Boolean operations:

```
n       a=     b=   c=    r=
=  bin  nAND4  a>>1 bXOR7 nANDc dec
0  000  000    000  111   000   0
1  001  000    000  111   001   1
2  010  000    000  111   010   2
3  011  000    000  111   011   3
6  110  100    010  101   100   4
7  111  100    010  101   101   5
```

You need to translate this into Pythonian. Assuming there is a logarithm base 2 (otherwise convert as shown above), here denoted with `lg(b)`, where `b` is your input byte, then all in all you have this

## Result

```
r = ((((lg(b)) And 4 ) >> 1) Xor 7) And lg(b)
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with each key-value pair consisting of a possible value of `byte` as the key, and the corresponding result as the value.

```
result = {
  1: 0,
  2: 1,
  4: 2,
  8: 3,
  64: 4,
  128: 5
}[byte]
```

Do note that this solution will throw an exception if `byte` has a value that is not in the dictionary. You need only slightly modify it to check for different values:

```
result = {
  1: 0,
  2: 1,
  4: 2,
  8: 3,
  64: 4,
  128: 5
}.get(byte, -1)
```

This will give a result of -1 if `byte` is not one of the keys.

Comment: @haccks Earlier version?

Comment: Never mind. I was talking about the one liner you posted before your first edit.

Answer (score 2):

use a dictionary maybe?

```
options = {
  1: 0,
  2: 1,
  4: 2,
  8: 3,
  64: 4,
  128: 5
}
def get_value(x):
    return options.get(x, default_val)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
byte_dict = {'1':0, '2':1, '4':2, '8':3, '64':4, '128':5}
return byte_dict[str(byte)]
```